# How to enable virtualization (Vtx) on Microsoft Surface book

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, uefi

I am attempting to enable virtualization on my Microsoft Surface book. I am only able to access the UEFI, but do not know how to make any of the necessary changes there. Is there a way to enable in UEFI, or is it possible to access the BIOS? Thank you for the help!

UPDATE: 
In my case, VTx was already enabled, and it is possible that this is the standard for Microsoft Surface book. To check, open command prompt, and type system info. Scroll to the bottom of the output, and find the Hyper-V requirements section.

```
Hyper-V requirements        VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
                            Virtualization Enabled In Firmware: Yes
                            Second Level Address Translation: Yes
                            Data Execution Prevention Available: Yes
```

If then virtualization enabled in firmware =  yes then you should be good.

Comment: In the past, previous Surface products came with it already enabled.  UEFI is firmware in a case like this.  **The Surface Book has a UEFI, not a BIOS firmware.**  There are numerous reasons you would think you don't have Vt-x enabled when you actually do, but an application is installed, is using it (security software, core isolation, ect). [Sic](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfbook-surfdrivers/enable-vt-x-on-surfacebook/b6dfb4fc-f2ec-4671-84ee-6d8596517130).  Run `Intel Processor Identification Utility` and see if it's enabled or disabled and update the question

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what each aspect of this comment means, but it made me go and check if VTx was enabled and it was.

Comment: Since VT-x is actually enabled, do you have a question?  What problem are you trying to solve by enabling VT-x?

Comment: I was unaware that is was enabled by default. I was trying to turn it on so my VMWare guest would work. Thank you for making me check.